# How can I obtain command returning status in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

Say, I call `grep "blabla" $file` in my shell. How could I know whether grep found "blabla" in $file?

I try `ret='grep "blabla" $file'`, will this work by viewing the value of `ret`? If yes, is `ret` integer value or string value or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do exactly

```
ret='grep "blabla" $file'
```

then `ret` will contain the string "grep "blabla" $file".

If you do (what you meant)

```
ret=`grep "blabla" $file`
```

then `ret` will contain whatever output `grep` spit out (the lines that matched "blabla" in `$file`).

If you just want to know whether `grep` found any lines that matched "blabla" in `$file` then you want to check the return code of `grep -q blabla "$file"` (note that you don't need to quote literal strings when they don't contain special characters and that you *should* quote variable references).

The variable `$?` contains the return code of the most recently executed command. So

```
grep -q blabla "$file"
echo "grep returned: $?"
```

will echo the return code from `grep` which will be `0` if any lines were output.

The simplest way to test that and do something about it is, however, not to use `$?` at all but instead to just embed the `grep` call in an `if` statement like this

```
if grep -q blabla "$file"; then
    echo grep found something
else
    echo grep found nothing
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run the command

```
grep blabla "$file"
```

Status is saved in the variable `$?`. 0 is good, greater than 0 is bad. So you
could do

```
grep -q blabla "$file"
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
  echo found
fi
```

Or save to a variable

```
grep -q blabla "$file"
ret=$?
if [ $ret = 0 ]
then
  echo found
fi
```

Or just use `if` with `grep` directly

```
if grep -q blabla "$file"
then
  echo found
fi
```